# ValueError: The model is not configured to compute accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

When using this code I got from some tutorial I got the error that says The model is not configured to compute accuracy and that I should pass accuracy , The weird part is I am already passing metrics = ['accuracy']

I've searched a lot and all the codes I have seen works fine except mine.

## Evaluating the ANN

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential #Used to initialize the NN
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense #Used to create the layers in the ANN

def build_classifier():
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu',input_dim = 11))
    classifier.add(Dense(units= 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics= ['accuracy'])
    return classifier
# Needs to be revised from evaluting video in the course if needed
classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier, batch_size = 10, nb_epoch = 100)
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = classifier, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 10, n_jobs = -1)
```

I expect the output to be the accuarcies vector, instead i got:

> ValueError: The model is not configured to compute accuracy. You should pass `metrics=["accuracy"]` to the `model.compile()` method.

Comment: Can you try `metrics=['acc']`?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I tried it now, I didn't get the same error, instead the model is training for 2 seconds (That's neraly 1/10 of the time taken for training the model using the fit method) and the accuracy is very low

Comment: Can you share your dataset or part of it?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters Here it is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GyyABXPxqjbc4RVSsaJtV6Vo6NqNPhms

Comment: What does `classifier.model.metrics_names` give you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the parameter from metrics=['accuracy'] by metrics=['acc'] works for me.

Regards,
Joseph

Comment: worked for me too.
The metrics 'val_accuracy' has changed to 'val_acc' as well!

Comment: it has changed with version 2.0, I believe, so it was indeed changing to acc.  The tip of @EliadL is also helpful: classifier.model.metrics_names